# Regex for splitting a string with some conditions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

this is my problem, I'm not very good with regular expressions, I need split a string in this way, for example I have this string:

```
1002;string1<br>
string2<br>
string3
1003;string1<br>
string2<br>
string3
```

So I need to split the whole string in this way: separating each item block, in the above case: one of them would be:

```
1003;string1<br>
string2<br>
string3
```

I've tried to split by `$data = explode("\n", $string);` but it separates each line, and I want to ignore if the `\n` is preceded by `<br>`, I suppose I have to use regular expressions, maybe using the `preg_split()` function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$matches = preg_split('/(?<!<br>)\n/', $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW9xP4/3)

This will split the input when `<br>` is not there before `\n`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, but I exactly need the regular expression that splits by \n not preceded by by <br>. Above scenario is just an example not exactly the same problem I have. Thanks!

Comment: **splits by \n not preceded by by <br>** will also split after `1002` and after `1003` and that won't match your expected output.